# Only one sculpt brush showing up

Tags: sculpting

Only one sculpting brush shows up on startup.
How do I get all the ones back that come with Blender?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: maybe load the factory settings? (file --> load factory settings)

Answer (score 1):

I hate loading factory default because of all the settings/theme that I would have to reset.
Downloading and installing a new version did not fix the problem either.
So, I had Blender on another computer with it's startup.blend on dropbox, I just opened that and saved it as the new start up file.
All brushes were there now.
Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I know of two more choices if restore to factory settings doesn't work for you. The first is to append another saved blender file. File>Append choose file and browse to the brushes. The second is to reinstall blender.